# Custom camera recorder preview get stretched when MediaRecorder.start() gets called

Tags: android, camera

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
camera.unlock();
recorder.setCamera(camera);
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
recorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(currentCamType,CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH)); 
recorder.setOutputFile(/*path of output file*/);
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
```

In the above code preview is getting changed(get stretched) when recorder.start() gets called yet I am not set the preview display of media recorder by MediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(). I have used camera.setPreviewDisplay() once when surface view is created. I think recorder.setProfile() in the above code is responsible for stretching the video.

Comment: Any luck figuring this out?

Comment: have you ever figured this one out?

Comment: any luck fixing this ?

Comment: Same here with device Xiaomi 4.

Comment: @user1041858 ... Did u resolve these problem..i have also stucked in the same problem..plz help me out to post the answer of these question